# Catalog Price Discounts vs. Shopping Cart Discounts

Tags: discount

When you setup a discount on, for example, a category of products using the catalog price discount admin area, should that effect your shopping cart too or should you need to setup an additional rule for the shopping cart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you setup catalog price rule discount, the discounted price will be shown in the product view page as the products actual price. When you add to cart, the product is added to cart with the discounted price. This is useful if you want to provide discount on specific products.

As for shopping cart discount, the products prices shown will be the normal price associated with the product. But when you fulfill certain criteria in the cart you get certain discount (lets say when a customer purchases products worth more than $500, he gets 10% discount). This discount will be applied to the cart total.